# Calling a variable from another function inside another file

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a dictionary variable from a function inside A.py, to my new python file B.py. However, it doesn't seem to bring it along. codedict is the variable I'm importing.

**Python file A.py**

```
import csv

def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:  
        reader = csv.reader(datafile)    
        next(reader)
        global codedict
        codedict = sorted({k[1].lower() for k in reader})   
load("Dataforcars.cvs")
```

In my new python file, I'm trying to bring along the dictionary.

**Python file B.py**

```
import csv
from A import load

print(codedict)
```

However, "codedict" is not defined in **B.py**.

Comment: I would recommend you reading the basics of OOP in python. There is big mistake in how you are using it.

Comment: @Prashant Kumar Hello, thanks for the response. I'll try to read more on it, however, could you kindly explain the places where I'm using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will helpful:

`A.py`:

```
import csv

def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:  
        reader = csv.reader(datafile)    
        next(reader)
        return sorted({k[1].lower() for k in reader})
```

`B.py`:

```
import csv
from A import load
codedict = load("Dataforcars.cvs")
print(codedict)
```

Comment: You should remove the line `global codedict` in `A.py`.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I now understand that the .csv file didnt come along since its outside of the function I'm calling in B.py.

Answer (score 0):

Codedict is local variable, you should return it rather than try to access it directly.

Comment: If I try to return the codedict, by using return codedict under the variable. Then everything below the return will not work.

Comment: That's true. You should always put return at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks, I put the "return codedict" at the end of my function. Then using the help from CC7052, I managed to call it.